# Is there a way to assign an object property to an array?

Tags: php

Pretty sure there is a way to do this but what I tried so far does not work

Consider we have an object $localDB with some properties, I was looking for a clean way to build the $connexionInfo array without casting $localDB or using a foreach loop.

```
// This would be too easy if it worked 
$connexionInfo = array( "UID"      => $localDB->uid, 
                        "PWD"      => $localDB->pwd, 
                        "Database" => $localDB->DB
                       );

// tried using {} a few different ways, also does not seem to work
$connexionInfo = array( "UID" => {$localDB->uid}, 
                        "PWD" => {$localDB->pwd}, 
                         "Database"=>  {$localDB->DB} 
                       );
```

I'm pretty sure there is a clean way to do this. Anyone?

UPdate:
     // Contrary to what I posted above ... this DOES actually do what it's supposed to!

```
 $connectionInfo = array("UID" => $localDB->uid, "PWD" =>$localDB->pwd, "Database"=> $localDB->DB);
```

Comment: I don't understand, what's wrong with the first method?

Comment: Assigning object properties in an array construct is syntactically correct. What's your problem with it? Do you get any error message?

Comment: @JohnP -> Nothing ! I retried it out of curiosity knowing it just looked right ... and it worked.

Comment: So problem solved? There's nothing wrong with what you did, Don't be afraid to experiment ^_^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in a comment under initial question, this is how one can assign obj properties to an array value:

```
$connectionInfo = array("UID" => $localDB->uid, "PWD" =>$localDB->pwd, "Database"=> $localDB->DB);
```

Answer (score 2):

use this function

```
function objectToArray($object)
{
    $array=array();
    foreach($object as $member=>$data)
    {
        $array[$member]=$data;
    }
    return $array;
}
```

You can try type casting your PHP 5 object to an array.

```
$array = (array) $localDB;
```

without casting or foreach then see the manual

#### [get_object_vars](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-object-vars.php)

Comment: OP said : without casting $localDB or using a foreach loop.

Comment: also see [get_object_vars](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-object-vars.php)

Answer (score 0):

depending on the levels within the object you can just do

```
$array = (array) $object;
```

If you want arrays within the array you will have to use some kind of recursion
(I think, this was all I needed so I didn't test any further for my case)

But it looks like this would be a cleaner version of what you want